# Swift array with another array reference to get values

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

My scenario, I have two separate array with same count. I am showing `array_one` into my picker or table. I don’t show `array_two` but `array_one` I will show in `table or picker` view. when user click particular index I can get `array_one` value but same time I need to get relevant ID(array_two) also. How to do that, Please provide some sample.

```
   Var array_one = [“Hindi”,”English”,”Bengali”,”Telugu”,”Odia”]
   Var array_two = [“05”,”02”,”08”,”02”,”09”]
```

Above, array I have `language and ID`. I am listing language in picker or tableview when i select language relevant index ID also I need to get. `Output like: “Hindi, 05"`

Comment: How are you getting the array_one values now? Also you could combine them both as an array of `struct` where your `struct` would have both the values.

Comment: I am getting from JSON. I am not good at struct so i am doing separate array to appending my JSON values @Rakesha Shastri

Comment: Use only on array because these values are synchronized: let array = [["id": "01", "language": Hindi"], ["id": "02", "language": English"]...], then in your picker where you do `array_one[row]`, do instead `array_one[row]["id"]`.

Comment: If you are not good with structs, you have some serious reading to do. I suggest you go through the basics of Swift and learn how to use the basic data structures to make your life easier.

Comment: Sure, I will Thanks dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let array_one = ["Hindi","English","Bengali","Telugu","Odia"]
let array_two = ["01","02","03","04","05"]

let language = "Hindi"

guard let index = array_one.index(of: language) else {
    fatalError("Couldn't find the language")
}

let languageId = array_two[index]

let output = language + ", " + languageId


print(output) //"Hindi, 01"
```

---

Actually, `array_two` is not needed:

```
let array_one = ["Hindi","English","Bengali","Telugu","Odia"]

let language = "Hindi"

guard let index = array_one.index(of: language) else {
    fatalError("Couldn't find the language")
}

let languageId = String(format: "%02d", index + 1)

let output = language + ", " + languageId
```

---

Here is a solution using `zip`:

```
let array_one = ["Hindi","English","Bengali","Telugu","Odia"]
let array_two = ["01","02","03","04","05"]
let zipped = zip(array_one, array_two)

let language = "Hindi"

guard let index = array_one.index(of: language),
    let languageAndId = zipped.first(where: {$0.0 == language
    })
else {
    fatalError("Couldn't find the language")
}

let output = languageAndId.0 + ", " + languageAndId.1

print(output)  //prints "Hindi, 01"
```

---

And to have an Object-Oriented Programming approach, use structs:

```
let array_one = ["Hindi","English","Bengali","Telugu","Odia"]
let array_two = ["01","02","03","04","05"]

struct Language {
    let name: String
    let index: String
}

let languagesArray: [Language] = zip(array_one, array_two).map{Language(name: $0.0, index: $0.1)}

let language = "Hindi"

guard let languageAndId = languagesArray.first(where: {$0.name == language
    }) else {
    fatalError("Couldn't find the language")
}

let output = languageAndId.name + ", " + languageAndId.index

//prints "Hindi, 01"
```

Comment: Wow. Great I will try and let you know here. Thanks dear @Carpsen90

Comment: @macoapp Could you please explain this question more? I don't understand what you want to do with the textField

Comment: Come on. Use zip

Comment: @macoapp I am glad could help!

Comment: great help @Carpsen90

Comment: Hi @Carpsen90 I don't want to get index value. I want to get exact id value from array_two.

Comment: @macoapp In all four solutions above, the *exact id value* is named: `languageId`, `languageAndId.1` or `languageAndId.index`

Comment: Hi  @Carpsen90 I have another one doubt. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52387115/swift-get-values-from-json-and-append-into-array?noredirect=1#comment91718915_52387115

Answer (score 1):

You can use a computed property that zips the two arrays:

```
var languages = { return zip(array_one, array_two).map{ "\($0.0), \($0.1)" } }
```

This will zip the 2 arrays, and map each pair of values to a comma separated string.  Since it is computed, any changes to the original arrays will automatically appear. So now you can use `languages` as the data source.

Comment: great..Its new, I will try this too. Thank you so much @meggar

Comment: Could you please describe bit more. @meggar

Answer (score 0):

> I have two separate array with same count.

Trying to keep two or more arrays synchronized is never a good idea -- it's too easy to add or remove something from one array and forget to update the other(s), and that makes this approach a constant source of serious bugs.

A better way to do it is to keep all the corresponding pieces of data together in some sort of data structure, and store those structures in a single array. That eliminates the possibility of forgetting to update all the arrays, because there's only one to worry about. Different languages support this approach in different ways; Swift gives us tuples. You can define your array like this:

```
var array = [("Hindi", "01"),
             ("English", "02"),
             ("Bengali", "03"),
             ("Telugu", "04),
             ("Odia", "05")]
```

Now you've got both sets of data in a single array, and you can access the parts separately:

```
let third_language = array[3].0
let third_id = array[3].1
```

But you can also name the parts of the tuple if you want:

```
var array : [(language:String, id:string)] = [("Hindi", "01"),
                                              ("English", "02"),
                                              ("Bengali", "03")]
let third = array[3]
print(third.language)    // prints "Bengali"
print(third.id)          // prints "03"
```

Comment: Great. btw how to merge two arrays because I am getting values from JSON and loading two separate arrays. so need to merge as per your idea and want to show language in table but when I select to print language with id.@Caleb